# Gruff translation of ん

Tags: slang, anime

I am trying to translate the following line:

> 「ン…そこにすわっていろ」

This line occurs after the gruff villain of the story is handed some files he asked for.

It seems that "Yes...sit down over there." would not be appropriate in this situation.

Possibilities I considered:

1. Alright
2. Yea
3. Hmph
4. Okay

None of these seem like the correct fit. Any opinions?

Comment: We need to know more context, like, what has just been said right before the line, etc.

Answer (score 2):

「ン」 in this context might possibly be sort of an abbreviation of 「うん」or「うむ」or even somewhat closer in nuance to 「おい」 because this is how someone with authority might speak to someone of lower status... 
So your translation to English might be something close to「Hmph」 or 「hey」 as in 「hey...sit over there.」

As you may know, it is hard to think of languages in terms of direct translation word for word. Some nuance only exist in certain culture.

Comment: How is it closer to 「おい」?  One could not tell from the context given.

Answer (score 1):

This ン is written in katakana, not hiragana, which means  that the ン sound was not fully pronounced. He seemed to just brusquely make a very short deep noise with his throat to show that it was not a bad time for him to receive the files.

He didn't use a word to express that. So, any English word may not fit the ン-like noise. How about looking for a throat noise expression, like "Mmm-hmm" or something?

I'm Japanese and unfortunately don't have enough English vocabulary to find the best expression in English. Sorry. Hope this answer is somewhat helpful.